# How can I speed up Scrapy Crawl?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a website, and I have a record of size 100K+.
The script at the moment is crawling @ 9pages/min.
Is it taking too much time? How can I speed up this process?

Comment: buy more servers on [ScrapingHub.com](https://scrapinghub.com/)

Comment: Do you use any proxy servers in your settings?

Comment: Did you look at the logs? Which operations take more time? Is it e.g. the site answering very slowly?

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things you can try to see if they work for you:

- If you're using auto-throttle (AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED), try disabling it and lower the DOWNLOAD_DELAY variable in the settings. By doing this you risk getting banned though.
- With AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED set to True, you can play around with DOWNLOAD_DELAY (minimum delay time) and AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY (maximum delay time).
- Another variable that you can change is the CONCURRENT_REQUESTS (and CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP & CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN). Putting a higher value here might speed up the crawling, but you again have an increased risk of getting banned.
- Using proxies for your requests while lowering the DOWNLOAD_DELAY and raising the number of CONCURRENT_REQUESTS can speed up the crawling with less risks of getting banned. You might overload the server of the website you're crawling though.
- A more scalable approach is to distribute the requests over multiple servers. You can do this for example by assigning different parts of the website to different servers, or by using a solution like Scrapy Cluster ([Scrapy Cluster documentation](https://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

Comment: You should add `AUTO_THROTTLE=False`